# My (wrong) answer accepted, should I edit it to be correct?

Tags: discussion, edits, accepted-answer, etiquette, wrong-answers

I gave an answer that was about 1/3 correct on this question: [Clojure proxy and @Override?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821585/clojure-proxy-and-override/5821715#5821715)

The commenters pointed out that I basically missed the boat, but my answer was accepted. Should I edit my answer to be correct? The edit page says: "clarify meaning without changing it," and if I edit, the comments won't make any sense.

On the other hand, the answer is wrong.

Comment: Kudos to you for following up instead of just taking the rep and running!

Comment: Wikipedia has a policy that StackOverflow should learn from: [Ignore All Rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Ignore_all_rules): _"If a rule prevents you from improving or maintaining Wikipedia, ignore it."_ Seems the answer to your question is rather obvious now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If it is your own answer, then it is fine to revise it to be a different meaning, because it'll still be *your* meaning. It's encouraged to be revising your own incorrect answers into correct ones.

The edit warning about clarification without changing applies moreso to editing the posts of other users. If it's not Community Wiki, then it's a bit crude to put words in other people's mouths, y'know?

Now, if this was a matter of *just copying* other people's answers into your own just because yours was the one accepted... not so nice to do. But that has less to do with "revising an incorrect accepted answer" and more "stealing other people's answers". If you're just revising an incorrect accepted answer of your own, whether or not there are other answers, that's typically acceptable.

Comment: @Brigham, I agree with this; content is king. Bad information won't help future visitors, or even the OP, who has presumably already been sufficiently helped. If you're really worried about it, you can leave an @name notification for the OP to highlight that you made changes, in case the OP wants to un-accept the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Without a full understanding of the concepts in the question, I can't give a really good answer here. But, that said, remember that

> The accepted answer is the one that the OP of the question has determined **best helped them**.

It may be that the question wasn't fully spec'd and was thus missing some nuggets of information, or that the OP used what you'd said to push themselves in the right direction. If you feel that your answer is wrong, by all means *edit it* or even consider adding another *more correct* answer, though if you do, edit your original answer to include a note pointing to the new one and explaining why you've left the original alone.

It may also be worth attempting to elicit a response from the questioner in comments as to why they considered your answer correct, so you can refine your answer, and their question, accordingly.